# Como verificar se existe o atalho da aplicação no Desktop, se não existir criar um

Tags: delphi

Estou usando Delphi XE7, queria saber como verificar se minha aplicação já contém um atalho no Desktop, se caso não existir criar um atalho.

Pelo que eu pesquisei, teria que olhar pelo registro do windows, alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar se algum dos ícones possui o alvo que você está pesquisando. A seguinte função pode ser útil.

```
uses
    Winapi.ShellAPI, 
    Winapi.ShlObj, 
    System.Win.ComObj, 
    System.Win.Registry, 
    Winapi.ActiveX

function ArquivoPeloLink(const NomeLink: String): String;
var
  AObject: IUnknown;
  ASLink: IShellLink;
  APFile: IPersistFile;
  WNomeLink: WideString;
  PFD: TWin32FindData;
begin
  AObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  ASLink := AObject as IShellLink;
  APFile := AObject as IPersistFile;

  WNomeLink := NomeLink;
  APFile.Load(PWideChar(WNomeLink), 0);
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  ASLink.GetPath(PChar(Result), MAX_PATH, PFD, 0);
end;
```

[Tirei daqui](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27241571/how-to-get-shortcut-link-target-in-delphi-2009.html). Uso:

```
LinkArquivo := ArquivoPeloLink('C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Atalho.lnk')
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar, vou dar uma analisada na sua resposta, se eu tiver sucesso marco ela.

Comment: Dá pra usar também a variável de ambiente Windows `%HOMEPATH%` que aponta para o diretório definido para o usuário atual.
Basta usar a função citada em conjunto com `GetEnvironmentVariable` caso não queira criar um atalho publico.